# UIRefreshControl text overlays on refresh-indicator

Tags: objective-c, overlay, ios7, uirefreshcontrol

I start with programming under XCode 5 with iOS 7 SDK. And when I create `UITableViewController` with `UIRefreshControl` with 'attributedText' I've got text overlayed on top of `UIRefreshControl` graphics (circle progress animation).

But when I pull down and release my finger, text jumps to its normal position. Why it happened?

```
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(updateDeviceList) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Update Devices States"];

    self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
```

**Before pulling down to the end:**

[image: Before pulling down to the end]

**After `UIRefreshControl` release:**

[image: After UIRefreshControl release]

Comment: See my answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121276/uirefreshcontrol-incorrect-title-offset-during-first-run-and-sometimes-title-mis

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Please try this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull to Refresh"];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.refreshControl = refreshControl;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    });

}
```

Comment: Additionally, if you've added the refresh control through interface builder, just exposed your existing control in your class and then use the dispatch_async as in this answer. That'll let you set your variables in IB and results in less code.

Comment: Works. Assuming there is a bug in apples code as I cannot imagine they intended this solution.

Comment: Apple did not fix this problem, yet ! Thank you for your little "hack" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Call `layoutIfNeeded` after setting title

```
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(updateDeviceList) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Update Devices States"];
[self.refreshControl layoutIfNeeded];
```

Answer (score -3):

Change your code to following

```
self.refreshControl = [UIRefreshControl new];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(updateDeviceList) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Update Devices States"];

self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
```

That should fix your problem