# Change UIRefreshControl title before showing it - Objective-c iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uirefreshcontrol

Is it possible to change the UIRefreshControl title before it appear on screen ?

Actually, I use this code to change the title in my update method :

```
NSString *refreshControlTitle = @"Pull to refresh...No new item to show";
NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.35 green:0.78 blue:0.98
                                                                                                   alpha:1.0]
                                                                            forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
NSAttributedString *attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:refreshControlTitle attributes:attrsDictionary];
refreshControl.attributedTitle = attributedTitle;
```

(Some text changes are done depending on the situation), but the text is only changing after the refresh is done.

How could I do to actualize the text just before the user begin to see the refreshControl ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: where u called this refresh method

Comment: see this once it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121276/uirefreshcontrol-incorrect-title-offset-during-first-run-and-sometimes-title-mis

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I call my refresh method from scrollViewDidEndDecelerating and the link provided doesn't help me :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (void) scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
}
```

try to put title in this method